# How can I remove table prefixes from a SQL dump?

Tags: sql, mysql, parsing

I have a `*.sql` file which is dumped from PHPMyAdmin, and all of the tables have a prefix of `ff_`. How can I remove this? I tried using Notepad++, but it doesn't work because the insert data contains the word too.

Comment: Have you tried sed? In windows, you can install cygwin to get sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like "`ff_" to "`". In simple notepad, notepad++ or sed.
Sed here isn't something different.
For this simple replacement you should create your dump to be forced with "`" around table names.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed is here to help:

```
sed -i 's/`ff_/`/g' *.sql
```

On Mac look for `gsed` instead of `sed`. Note the backtick in patterns.

If you think that one of your files contains `` `ff_ `` in a string other than table name, you can check that with:

```
grep '`ff_' *.sql
```

If this is the case, consider the following:

```
sed -i 's/INSERT INTO `ff_/INSERT INTO `/g' *.sql
```

Comment: Note this part of the OP: _"he insert data contains the word too"_, which is what this sed-replacement will also replace.

Comment: I meant, I could not use the replace from: `'ff_'` to `''` (empty), because maybe, in the content which from inserted data is exist this word too.

Comment: @vietean, it could mean one of 2 things: either "original poster" (which would be you), or "original post" (which is what I meant).

Comment: @vietean, then you cannot use this suggestion: this `sed`-replacement makes no distinction between table names that start with `\`ff_` and `"... \`ff_ ... "` inside data (string literals).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3612/discussion-between-vietean-and-bart-kiers)